# SPARQL query for retrieving individuals

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege

Please help me with the SPARQL query.
I have an ontology with the class 'Building' as a subclass of `owl:Thing`. 'Building' has it's own sub classes like: Church, Medical, Shop.
Each of these sub classes has it's own labels ( `seeAlso` ). For instance: Shop has labels like supermarket, bakery, market etc. Church has labels like Chapel, Cathedral etc.

[image]

The Individuals look like this:

[image]

I need to do a SPARQL query, which will retrieve the individuals according to the labels.
So let's say I want to get all the individuals of that subclass which has the labels of type `seeAlso` "bakery". In this case I expect to get bakery1 and supermarket1

I have tried this, but it seems like this query is wrong:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT ?individual ?class ?label
WHERE { 
    ?individual rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .
    ?class rdf:type owl:Class .
    FILTER(?label="bakery")
}
```

If I delete the line with `FILTER` , I will get only the individuals and classes, but not related to each other as they should. Protege just returns me all the possible connections Class - Individual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given comments to the answer, the intent is to build synonyms, not separate instances.  There are a few ways to do this, but [SKOS](https://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/) is specifically designed for such vocabulary relationships.  The property `skos:prefLabel` is used for the display label, and synonyms can be defined by `skos:altLabel`.  The hierarchy you have can be retained, just use `skos:altLabel` instead of 'rdf:seeAlso' (which is normally used for reference links ourtide of the ontology).

So the data, in a Turtle text serialization would look like:

```
:Shop rdfs:subClassOf :Building .
:Shop skos:prefLabel "Shop"^^xsd:string .
:Shop skos:altLabel "supermarket"^^xsd:string .
:Shop skos:altLabel "bakery"^^xsd:string .
:Shop skos:altLabel "market"^^xsd:string .
```

For the query, the OP says to match by the string - the `preflabel` in this case:

```
SELECT ?individual ?label
WHERE {
   ?individual skos:prefLabel "Shop"^^xsd:string .
   ?individual skos:altLabel ?label
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is really helpful! Thank you so much!

Comment: Excuse me, my question might seem silly, but: how should I use skos? Should it be dataProperty or Annotation as a Literal or any other way?
I'm using Protege and I tried to install Skos Editor, but I couldn't figure out how could I assign skos properties to my Classes.

Comment: It's a vocabulary in RDF.  You should be able to download and/or import it from the SKOS link in the response.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is all of the instances of the class `:Building` and its subclasses.  Also note that if `?label` is not bound, the filter will always fail.  So you'll need to do the following:

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>SELECT 
WHERE {
   ?cls rdfs:subClassOf* :Building .
   ?individual a ?cls .
   ?individual rdfs:seeAlso ?label .
   FILTER (?label = "bakery")
}
```

…and that is a classic anti-pattern for SPARQL.  As much as possible, you should use basic graph patterns, so this is a more correct query:

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>SELECT 
WHERE {
   ?cls rdfs:subClassOf* :Building .
   ?individual a ?cls .
   ?individual rdfs:seeAlso "bakery" .
}
```

Note the third triple pattern uses the literal in the triple pattern.  Also, I don't think the model you have should be using `rdfs:seeAlso` for the label of the instance.  Instead I'd suggest a separate instance for each kind Shop, etc. and use `rdfs:label` to represent the label of the instance.

Lastly, if you need to do an inexact match you can use `regex`.  For example to find "bakery" regardless of case, use the following:

```sql
#-- …
?individual rdfs:seeAlso ?label .
FILTER regex(?label, "Bakery", "i")
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'm not sure regarding the separation of each instance and using rdfs:label. What I want to do is to assign a set of let's say synonyms to the class Shop. So that even if the word "supermarket" will be used, the program will know that what meant is Shop.

Comment: OK, in that case, I'd suggest using SKOS to represent synonyms.  Will create a second response...